# unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int' but different

Tags: python

I made a random palindrome generator. The program calculates the number of possible palindromes for a set char limit, calculating it using the char limit and letters in the English language with a math.ceil function. The section I am having problems with is as follows:

```
import math
maximum = input('Max length?')
for i in range (math.ceil(maximum / 2)):        
    power = power * 26
```

maximum is a variable containing the set char limit. I used this script because Python doesn't support the equation in LaTEX form.

However, whenever I run this script, it comes up with this error:

```
for i in range (math.ceil(maximum / 2)):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

I've tried using the `int()` function as `int(math.ceil(maximum / 2))`, but it pushes it back out as a *standard* drop-down window SyntaxError.

What's my problem?
Thanks!

Comment: If you read the error message, it clearly states that you are trying to divide a string with an integer. How would you approach fixing this?

Comment: Can you show your use of the `int()` function, and the `SyntaxError` you receive? Please make sure your indentation is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were so close :) On the right track with int() on that line, just scoped on the wrong variable.

In Python 3, input() returns a str by default. The error message clearly indicates that the error occurs on the `/` operator, and it is because the variable `maximum` is a str (since the other argument is an int). Can't divide a str by an int.

You can prove this to yourself, by doing

`type(input('some input'))`

`>>> <class 'str'>`

To fix, cast `maximum` as an int():

`for i in range (math.ceil(int(maximum) / 2)):`

or edit the input line:

`maximum = int(input('Max length?'))`

Comment: Thanks, it fixed that problem. I tried declaring 'maximum' as an integer before in the var creation line and it didn't work.